# Wireshark Remote system packets capturing

Tags: wireshark

How can we capture packets of a remote system without installing wincap on the remote systems ? Is it possible to capture the packets ?

Comment: It can be done by installing wincap on the remote systems but how can we achieve it without installing the software on the remote system

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you're in the same L2 segment. Check wonderful and detailed [tutorial](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) from wireshark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @HarishReddy no problems. If answer clears your concerns, you should mark it as "accepted".